# Links not working in Font Awesome Social media Icon Menu

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to make a social media menu, the Font Awesome Icons are all visible and the way I want but the hyperlink is not working on it.....

Here is my code:

```css
.sm-list {
  display: flex;
}

.sm-link {
  color: #929FC5;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 1px solid #929FC5;
  border-radius: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.sm-link:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.sm-link:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #A971FF, #00F0FF);
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="sm-list">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="sm-link">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="sm-link">
    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" class="sm-link">
    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="sm-link">
    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. I dont see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load the icons with the following code. You must first load the Font Awesome in the head tag

```
<head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          
</head>
        
<body>
          <div class="sm-list">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="sm-link">
               <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="sm-link">
               <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.twitter.com/" class="sm-link">
               <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="sm-link">
               <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
              </a>
            </div>       
</body>
```